# Problem understanding Linq query structure when involves filtering, flattening and grouping

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, ef-core-2.1

I'm facing a lot of problems trying to fetch data from this Data Model using LinqToEntities.

I'm working with EF Core 2.1 and Linq on a SQL Server database.

Basically I need to show events on a weekly calendar, but the data structure is quite complex.
Events could have multiple EventDate (every date is a single day with a starting and ending hour) and on each day many different Contacts partecipate sometimes on a different time than the generic one on the EventDate.

I need to filter them by a week period (Startdate, EndDate) and occasionally also by a list of contacts involved.

The main problem is  that I need to extract a list of distinct objects (filtered as requested) one for each EventDate but with all the overrides grouped within it and with the list of contacts for each override group, like this sample structure:

```
EventID,
EventName, 
//...Other Data from Events
FromDateTime, //Taken from the EventDate Table
ToDateTime, //Taken from the EventDate Table
//...Other Data from EventDates
Overrides:[
    //Taken from the EventDateContact Table
    {
        OverrideFromHour, 
        OverrideToHour 
        Contacts [contactid, contactid, ...] 
    },
    {
        OverrideFromHour,
        OverrideToHour
        Contacts [contactid, contactid, ...]
    }
]
```

I'm still having problems understanding LinqToEntities on very complex queries.

In a non EF/Linq application I would have done a Join between tables then iterated on the results grouping manually as needed, but I'm wondering if is there a way to do this directly using LinqToEntities or mixing it with LinqToObjects woking in memory after one or diffenrent an initial queries.

I've tried different join and grouping but I can't figure out how make it works!

Here is the data model:

```
public class Event {

    public Event()
    {
        EventDates = new HashSet<EventDate>();
        EventDatesContacts = new HashSet<EventDatesContact>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    ...other data

    public virtual ICollection<EventDate> EventDates { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<EventDatesContact> EventDatesContacts { get; set; }
}


public class EventDate {

    public EventDate()
    {
        EventDatesContacts = new HashSet<EventDatesContact>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int EventID { get; set; }

    //The Date part remain the same between From and To. 
    //Only the Hour can change.
    public DateTime FromDateTime { get; set; }

    public DateTime ToDateTime { get; set; }

    //...other data

    public virtual Event Event { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<EventDatesContact> EventDatesContacts { get; set; }

}

public class EventDatesContact {

    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int EventID { get; set; }

    public int ContactID { get; set; }

    public int EventDateID { get; set; }

    //If not null these overrides the corresponding DateTime in the EventDate
    //The Date part remain the same between From and To and also the same as the linked EventDate. 
    //Only the Hour can change.
    public DateTime? OverrideFromTime { get; set; }

    public DateTime? OverrideToTime { get; set; }

    //...other data

    public virtual Contact Contact { get; set; }

    public virtual EventDate EventDate { get; set; }

    public virtual Event Event { get; set; }

}
```

Thank you in advance for any support!

Comment: LinqToSql is totally different (and quite obsolete) technology from LinqToEntities used in EF (Core). Probably by LinqToSql you actually mean LinqToEntities, while by LinqToEntities you mean LinqToObjects. It would be good if you correct the terminology in the post because currently it's confusing.

Comment: Other than that, the `Event` in `EventDatesContact` looks redundant and makes hard to follow the relationships. Shouldn't they be Event 1 .. N EventDate N .. N Contact?

Comment: Can you show what you have tried? It looks to me like you need two joins and two group bys.

Comment: @IvanStoev yes, sorry I used the wrong terms. Fixed now!
And regarding the redoundancy in the relations its true, I can remove it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use EF much, but you shouldn't need to join with EF. You should be able to just use the Navigation properties, but you will need to group since you are consolidating the `EventDate.EventDatesContacts` in your result. Here is my attempt:

```
var results = db.Events
                .Include(e => e.EventDates).ThenInclude(ed => ed.EventDatesContacts)
                .SelectMany(e => e.EventDates.Select(ed => new Result {
                    EventID = e.ID,
                    EventName = e.Name,
                    FromDateTime = ed.FromDateTime,
                    ToDateTime = ed.ToDateTime,
                    Overrides = ed.EventDatesContacts.GroupBy(edc => new {
                            FromTime = edc.OverrideFromTime == null ? ed.FromDateTime : edc.OverrideFromTime.Value,
                            ToTime = edc.OverrideToTime == null ? ed.ToDateTime : edc.OverrideToTime.Value
                        },
                        edc => edc.ContactID
                        )
                        .Select(edcg => new EventOverride {
                            OverrideFromHour = edcg.Key.FromTime,
                            OverrideToHour = edcg.Key.ToTime,
                            ContactIDs = edcg.ToList()
                        })
                        .ToList()
                }));
```

My understanding is you may not need the `Include` if you have eager loading enabled.

Comment: I've just added the filter on dates and contacts as i need to filter the results, and it's working. 
My doubt is that checking the generated query it seems to generate a lot of queries to fetch datas, it looks like one for each EventDate. 
Doesn't this create a performance problem on growing of Events number?

Comment: Yes, depending on size of data involved, it may not scale well. If you can show a single SQL query that generates what you want, I could use my [SQL to LINQ Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786) to try to translate to a better LINQ query, but EF Core isn't able to translate as much as EF yet (which is partly why use LINQ to SQL or EF instead).

Comment: YW. Note, not to be unfair to EF Core, some queries are faster if split up into multiple queries. Depends on data size, indexes, server performance, etc.

Comment: just one more question, is there any difference between adding a where filter on the EventDates subquery or concatenating it at the end?
Actually I need to compose the query dynamically adding different filters on Events, EventDates and EventContacts depending on parameters passed.

Comment: @ilFusta I think that would depend on your database provider, I would suggest testing with LINQPad or something similar.